# VB.netでString型から検索して最初の項目を取り出したい

Tags: vb.net

VB.netを練習しています。
例えば、String型で次のようなデータがあるとき、条件に一致したものを取り出したいと思っています。

a() = {“愛知県”, “岐阜県”, “三重県”, “愛媛県”}

このようなデータから

“愛知”をキーにしたら”愛知県”が得られる、”県”をキーにしたら”愛知県”が得られるというようなことがしたいです。
excelのVLOOKUPのようなイメージです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

色々方法はありますが、Linqを使う方法がシンプルに書けると思います。

```vb
Dim prefectures = {“愛知県”, “岐阜県”, “三重県”, “愛媛県”}

Dim results = From prefecture In prefectures
              Where prefecture.Contains("愛")
              Select prefecture

'最初の項目だけ出力（該当無しの場合はNothingになる）
Console.WriteLine(results.FirstOrDefault())

'一致した項目全てを出力
For Each result In results
    Console.WriteLine(result)
Next
```